# What browsers are supported by Magento's PWA Studio?

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio, browser

What browsers are supported by Magento's PWA Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Magento state PWA studio is "Cross-browser compatible - PWA sites work equally well on all modern browsers, such as Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari."

In other words, it will work on all popular browsers but NOT Internet Explorer.

See https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/overview/

To be more more specific they support browsers with more than 5% usage according to BrowserList:

> All functionality must work in any browser with more than 5% of market share, according to BrowserList.

See https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/wiki/Definition-Of-Quality#browser-support

Comment: Thank you @Ben Crook

Comment: If this answers your question can you please mark it as accepted (check/tick symbol to the left of the answer).